# How to access a Dataframe.index during creation / setup for method chaining

Tags: pandas

Historically, before the recent improvements to Pandas to improve method chaining, I'd often do a version of the following :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe(data_containing_date_column)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Rather than having multiple assignmentsm I'd like to be able to include this in a setup method chain that goes on to include `assign`, `rename`, etc.

Is there a way to access the DataFrame's 'self.index' without having a named dataframe to work with?

I have tried and failed with:

- `assign` - it creates a new column called index, rather than the index attribute.
- `apply` - the lambda approach within apply won't let me do the assignment needed to parse the datetimes.

(As context, with `pandas.read_csv()` you have `parse_dates=True` but no parallel in the core `pandas.DataFrame` method. That's essentially what I'm after here.)

Comment: You could define a function that does the assignment and pass it to apply.

Comment: How about `df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.to_datetime(column_with_dates))` with an additional `drop` to get rid of the date column in the data?

Comment: @IanS - yes that's a good idea, to define a separate function. Just hoping there was a `self.index` style method of accessing it to make it easier to do directly. The issue with your second suggestion is that the raw data isn't easily accessible (it's often an array) and in an ideal world I'd like to be able to avoid further pre-processing.

Comment: @ianS - no other replies so if you want to leave an answer, I'll mark as solved otherwise I'm happy to answer it.

Comment: I'll let you answer and explain why it's not what you were hoping for :) Thanks!